# the sum of projections is 1 in $B(H)$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space,can we find $n $ isometries $s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_n \in B(H)$ such that $1=s_1s_1^*+s_2s_2^*+\cdots s_ns_n^*$ ,where $1$ is the identity map from $H$ to $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed we can. Moreover these isometries will generate the well known Cuntz algebra (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuntz_algebra).

You can take an orthonormal basis $(e_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ for $\mathcal{H}$ (assuming $\mathcal{H}$ is separable here). Now partition $\mathbb{N} = N_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup N_n$ where $N_j = \{j + kn \mid k \geq 0\}$. Letting $f_j: \mathbb{N} \to N_j$ be bijections, we can let $S_je_k = e_{f_j(k)}$, extend by linearity and continuity. Then you can check that $(S_j)_{j=1}^n$ are $n$ isometries satisfying your relation (called the Cuntz relation).

Comment: I wonder the explicit expression of the $f_j$? $f_j(k)=?$

Comment: Well you can something like $f_j(k) = j + (k-1)n$. This will give very natural bijections between $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $\{j,j+n,j+2n,\dots\}$.
The map here doesn't matter too much though. The important bit is that $\mathcal{H} \simeq \oplus_{j=1}^n\mathcal{H}$ and this allows you to get these isometries easily: just take $S_i: \oplus_{j=1}^n\mathcal{H} \to \oplus_{j=1}^n\mathcal{H}$ be an isomorphism from $\oplus_{j=1}^n\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$, thinking of this copy of $\mathcal{H}$ as a direct summand.

Comment: I see,thanks!I have another question:should $Nj$ be the form of  $\{j + kn \mid k\in \Bbb Z^{+}\}$?

Comment: Well the way I've done it, the range projection $S_jS_j^*$ will be onto the subspace $\overline{\text{span}}(e_{j + kn})_{k=0}^{\infty}$: $k = 0$ corresponds do the basis vector $e_j$. If $N_j = \{j + kn \mid k > 0\}$ (I assume $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is the strictly positive integers here), then $S_1S_1^* + \cdots + S_nS_n^*$ will be a projection onto $\overline{\text{span}}(e_k)_{k={n+1}}^{\infty}$ and is therefore not the identity.

Comment: I thought the partition $N_j$ can be constrcuted as following:consider $n=2$,then $N=N_1\sqcup N_2$,where $N_1=\{2n,n\in \Bbb N\},N_2=\{2n+1,n\in \Bbb N\}$.When $n=3,$ then $N=N_1\sqcup N_2\sqcup N_3$,where $N_1=\{3n,n\in \Bbb N\},N_2=\{3n+1,n\in \Bbb N\},N_3=\{3n+2,n\in \Bbb N\},$\cdots

Comment: I mean $\mathbb{Z}^+=\Bbb N\cup \{0\}$

Comment: Right, then yes, $N_j = \{j + kn \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$.

In this example, I indexed my basis by $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,\dots\}$, and my sets $N_j$ are the set of positive integers $q$ such that $q \equiv j$ mod $n$.